# Background task affected by exception

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a task (download function) running in my main thread with all UI. When there is an exception in other parts of the program, the download function stops working as well. How can I make sure the download function remains unaffected?

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproducible code?

Comment: Maybe take a look at Zones: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-async/runZoned.html